# I want to remove the header from my csv writer (the output file)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove the header from my csv writer (the output file). Not sure what to do. Below is my code:

```py
def WriteToCSV(OutPutFile, dataOut):
    global logger

    try:
        with open(OutPutFile, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

            for data in dataOut :
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: is the header in the dataOut? Also what is dataOut's type?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a list of output data.
The 1st element is the CSV column headings.
[Simply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation#answer-509295) [elide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) it:

```
            for data in dataOut[1:]:
```